# count sub-elements of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a 2 dimensional array in PHP that looks like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 205
        [name] => Data Export
        [description] => A function to export survey results.
        [is_active] => Y
    )

...

[99] => Array
    (
        [id] => 206
        [name] => Data Import
        [description] => 
        [is_active] => N
    )
)
```

I want to determine how many items in my array don't have a description.

The function I've got so far looks like the below ...

```
function array_count ($array, $key) {
    // count($array[*][$key])
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($array as $i=>$subarray) {
        $c += ($subarray[$key]!='');
    }
    return $c;
}
```

... is there a better way to do this?

... how would I extend this to count for matches against a value, like `$array[*][is_active]=='Y'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking this might work:

```
function array_count ($array, $key, $value = NULL) {
    // count($array[*][$key])
    $c = 0;
    if (is_null($value)) {
        foreach ($array as $i=>$subarray) {
            $c += ($subarray[$key]!='');
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($array as $i=>$subarray) {
            $c += ($subarray[$key]==$value);
        }
    }
    return $c;
}
```

This way I can do the following:

```
// assume $foo is an array of 100 arrays, 
// of which 20 sub-arrays have a blank 'description', 
// and 35 have 'is_active' set to 'Y' and 65 set to 'N'

echo array_count ($foo, 'description'); // ... 80 non-blanks
echo array_count ($foo, 'is_active'); // ... 100 non-blanks
echo array_count ($foo, 'is_active', 'Y'); // ... 35 matches
echo array_count ($foo, 'description', ''); // ... 20 is-blanks
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_count ($array, $key, $value) {
    // count($array[*][$key])
    $c = 0;
    foreach ($array as $i=>$subarray) {
        $c += strcmp( $subarray[$key], $value) ) === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: Was it unwise to do ``$c += ($boolean);`` instead of ``$c += ($boolean) ? 1 : 0;``, or is that just a stylistic choice?

Comment: Stylistic. Both do he same I think. Not sure if there is a difference at the interpreter level.

Answer (score 0):

checking empty array:

```
if( 0 < ( $cnt = count($array) ) )
{
 echo "Your array size is: $cnt";
}
else
 echo "Too bad, your array is empty :(";
```

Answer (score -3):

use:-

```
foreach ($array as $i=>$value) {


//from this you get the all whole array description value then apply if else condition to         short out

echo $_POST[$i]['description']."</br>";

    }
```

Comment: i think this is better way,if it does not then i also want to know your most welcome.what wrong in it.

Comment: sorry,but i don't understand.what is correct way,i am here to learn and i also want to learn.It will thankful if any one explain.